# How to get catalog listing in ultracart

Tags: php, json

I m new to ultracart. I m trying to get listing of catalog(category). my server side language is php. although I found the product item list json using below code

```
function items() {

  var merchantId = 'MID';
  var items = '';
  items = items.split(','); 
  var url = 'https://secure.ultracart.com/catalog/MID/';

  var data = {
    _mid: merchantId,
    id: items,
    url: url
  };


  jQuery.ajax({
    url: './rest_proxy.php?_url=/rest/site/items',
    type: 'get',
    data: data,
    headers: {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"}, 
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (obj) {      
    var i=obj.length;
    var svalue='<table width="100%">';
    for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        dShort="";
        j=obj[i].attributes.length;
        for(j=0;j<obj[i].attributes.length;j++){
            if(obj[i].attributes[j].name=="Short")
                dShort=obj[i].attributes[j].value;            
        }
        svalue=svalue+'<tr><td width="120"><a href="productdetail.php?productid=' + obj[i].itemId + '"><img src="' + obj[i].defaultImageUrl + '" alt="" width="100" /></td><td valign="top"><a href="productdetail.php?productid=' + obj[i].itemId + '"><b>' + obj[i].description + '</b></a><br><br>' + dShort + '</td></tr>';
        svalue=svalue+'<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>';
    }
    svalue=svalue+'</table>';
    jQuery('#products').html(svalue);
      });
}
```

Please help.